# "Será" pode ter um significado como "realmente"?

Tags: português-brasileiro, significado-em-contexto

Eu vi que pessoas usam *será* em situações em que significa **’realmente’**.

Por exemplo:

> O professor não vem hoje. Será?

Então o significado é ’realmente’?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sim, "realmente" pode ser um sinônimo aproximado no caso.

O [será](https://www.dicio.com.br/sera/) aqui faz parte da construção fixa **será que**, em que o "que" foi omitido juntamente com o restante da pergunta: "será (que é) verdade?", "será que ele realmente não vai?", etc.

Essa construção é usada para expressar, e.g., incerteza ou dúvida. Outros exemplos:
Será que nunca esquecerei? (*Is it possible that I will never forget?*)
 Será que ele está morto? (*Could it be that he's dead?*)
 Mais sobre o "será que" pode ser encontrado nessa [questão](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/o-uso-de-sera-que/30355) do Cyberdúvidas.

Comment: Acho que não significa, realmente. Significa incerteza ou dúvida. Isso sim.

Comment: Oi @Lambie. O "realmente" só funciona com a intonação adequada. Com ela, também "mesmo?", "sério?" e outras palavras também funcionam.